# Will be another LTS sonarQube in 2019?

Tags: sonarqube

My team want to upgrate a global project environment, including sonarQube.
Will be there another LTS sonarQube in 2019 ?

Comment: See https://community.sonarsource.com/

Comment: Looking [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) they are planning for version 7.6 and 7.7. There are still no public plans for 8.x.

Answer (score 3):

SonarQube 6.7 was released on Nov 2017 and we generally release LTS every ~18 months. 
Our plan is to have a new SonarQube 7.x LTS around Q2 2019, and the current schedule targets end of May.

Comment: [SonarQube 7.9 LTS](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-9-lts/) was released 1 July 2019. [Here's more](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/lts/) on the LTS, including cycle length.